# Windows10 tag needs to be renamed to WindowsIoT

Tags: discussion

Windows10 tag is not a valid tag for the WindowsIoT

On Stack Overflow, WindowsIOT team monitor the `windows-10-iot-core` tag for issues.

This also raises a question where these questions should be asked for Raspberry Pi. Since I can a see split here (Pi) and there (SO) on various questions regarding IoT on Pi.

Its a shame that this stack exchange got left out complelty from the links at http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Community.htm

Comment: I don't neccesarily disagree, but I do have a few questions and comments. Your title says that the tag needs to be renamed, however this is a community and even though I can make the change I believe the decision should come from the community not a single user. Second, can you expand on why you feel that Windows10 is not a valid tag? Is one a superset of the other? If the WindowsIOT team monitor the windows-10-iot-core tag would it be more appropriate to use that tag here as well? How is a tag name change better than an alias or multiple tags?

Comment: With regards to where to ask a question this is not a new issue. We deal regularly with questions about the basics of linux python etc. and the community and moderators close and migrate questions as needed. Are you suggesting a change to the existing policies/faq with regards to scope?

Comment: Sorry I only saw these now. WIndows10 refers to the full desktop version, or ARM version of Mobile Windows 10(Which is Desktop capable becuse of the Universal Architecture). Windows-IOT is separate, runs on the `MicroFramework` of .NET and is not desktop capabale. WindowsIOT also runs on other embedded devices, Like Intel Galileo.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this since there will presumably be a "windows 11 IOT", etc., so I have merged `windows10` -> `windows-iot` and the former is now a synonym for the latter.

Of course, this may present an issue if 11 or 12 differs in some substantial aspect, but in that case we can just add an additional tag, `windows11`, also a lesser known heist film ;P.